# load a local css file into a webview

Tags: html, ios, css, webview

I built a simple ios app that loads a html downloaded from a server into a webview.

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:notif.html baseURL:nil];
```

This works perfect. The problem is that i nedd to apply a local css file to the webview and I dont know how to do it.

I tried doing it this way, but the styles are not being applied.

```
NSString *HTML_HEADER=@"<HTML><HEAD><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'></HEAD><BODY>";
NSString *HTML_FOOTER=@"</BODY></HTML>";
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",HTML_HEADER,notif.html,HTML_FOOTER]; 

NSLog(@"htmlString %@", htmlString);
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Any idea?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I tried to do the following:

```
NSString *HTML_HEADER=@"<HTML><HEAD><link rel='stylesheet' href='#FILE1#' type='text/css'></HEAD><BODY>";
    NSString *HTML_FOOTER=@"</BODY></HTML>";

    NSString *cssFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
    NSString *html_header_with_files = [HTML_HEADER stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#FILE1#" withString:cssFilePath];


    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",html_header_with_files,notif.html,HTML_FOOTER];

    NSLog(@"htmlString %@", htmlString);
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

And in Build Phases i have added the style.css

[image]

UPDATE 2:

I also check if the style.css exists with

```
 NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
    NSLog(@"\n\nthe string %@",filePath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is CSS and JS files not available at runtime for render in HTML.

You need to take care of some points:

1. All CSS/JS/HTML files must be added to **Project Properties** >> **Build Phases** >> **Copy Bundle Resources.**

Check that all files are added if not then manually add those files.

[image]

2. All files are should be placed in the same folder, so that reference file path will be available at run time.
3. Instead of using directly file names, I will prefer you to use marker. Use symbols as a marker to replace with actual path of CSS and JS files.

For example:

```
NSString *HTML_HEADER=@"<HTML><HEAD><link rel='stylesheet' href='#FILE1#' type='text/css'></HEAD><BODY>";
NSString *HTML_FOOTER=@"</BODY></HTML>";

NSString *cssFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
NSString *html_header_with_files = [HTML_HEADER stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#FILE1#" withString:cssFilePath];


NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",html_header_with_files,notif.html,HTML_FOOTER];

NSLog(@"htmlString %@", htmlString);
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

In above example I have replace `style.css` string from html part and add marker `#FILE1#`.

This marker is relative url to file `style.css` and it will be replace before html load in webView.

So whenever you would like to load html to webView, load all resource files from their relatives urls.

Here `HTML_HEADER` will be replace with actual path for all resources files.

Comment: I tried what you mention, but still not added styles. I modified my question with the new code.

Comment: @KepaSantos: Please provide your comments in english.

Comment: I think  `notif.html ` file also contains `href:` tag for JS or CSS. So that these files not able to load on runtime. Please check `notif.html` also.

Comment: I check and only has href: to images that are in urls.

Comment: You never use "HTML_HEADER" in your code, is that normal?

Comment: @Zil : Thanks for indication, I forgot to change variable in next line.

Answer (score 1):

You can import files (as CSS, JS ...) even without putting them into "Copy bundle resources", so you can just download CSS and use it during run of your app.

Trick is in setting "baseURL" parameter, which becomes root directory for your UIWebView.

```
// HTML file
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlFileName     ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// root directory
NSURL *rootDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:rootDir];
```

Then, when you say 
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

in your HTML file, app will look for style.css in rootDir directory (in this case, [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] )

Comment: But the style.css file is in my local. The one that i downloading is the html file.

Comment: Oh, so you want to prioritize your CSS over the one in HTML? I guess CSS directly in HTML file has higher priority than imported one so you would have to somehow remove css code from downloaded html. Regex could be the way

Comment: No, the html that I downloading is a <DIV> block and i need to embed into a html with some common styles.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution.

```
  NSString *HTML_HEADER=@"<HTML><HEAD><link rel='stylesheet' href='#FILE1#' type='text/css'></HEAD><BODY>";
    NSString *HTML_FOOTER=@"</BODY></HTML>";

    NSString *cssFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
    NSString *html_header_with_files = [HTML_HEADER stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#FILE1#" withString:cssFilePath];


    NSString *htmlString = [NSString      stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",html_header_with_files,notif.html,HTML_FOOTER];



   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

 NSLog(@"htmlString %@", htmlString);
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Its necessary to specify the bundlePath in loadHTMLString:

The solution is a combination of the two answers given by @Kampai and @itzprintz

Comment: I do same like you but it isn't work, uiwebview load local HTML and fine but styles in css are not append to HTML, can you point me how to fix that?