# Load a page from documents folder on ios

Tags: ios, swift3, wkwebview, xcode9

I have an App which moves all HTML files to my own folder on the iPhone: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD332281-2ADE-4809-ABF2-F3FC3004AF42/Documents/MOTHER-APP/index.html

and

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD332281-2ADE-4809-ABF2-F3FC3004AF42/Documents/MOTHER-APP/css/mother.css

The problem is when the App access's the index.html file no CSS files are available. I have tested if the index file and the CSS file exists and it is all there.

I have tried both:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(indexfile, baseURL: baseUrl)   
webView.loadFileURL(destinationURLForFile, allowingReadAccessTo: 
destinationURLForFile)
```

The HTML index file requests the CSS like this:

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mother.css" />
```

All of the above code works perfectly on any simulator but not on a real device

Comment: Try with below sample code `override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
    mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test/index", ofType: "html")!)))
}
`

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code please try with this code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
    mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test/index", ofType: "html")!)))
}
```

Another Sample code

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var URL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
URL = URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.html")

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: fileURL)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

### Update :

- How to load css file and .js file in web view visit below link

[load a local css file into a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762007/load-a-local-css-file-into-a-webview)

Comment: Hi, thanks @Vivek for the input, there were a few "this has been changed to" but I eventually got your code to run, the simulator works fine but the device does not load the page just a blank white background

Comment: `let fileManager = FileManager.default`
     var URL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: 
        .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURL = URL.appendingPathComponent("\ 
       (motherGlobals.DIR_MAIN)/index.html")
                      let request = URLRequest(url: fileURL)
        webView.load(request)`

Comment: Ok, Did you put your file into your document folder ? First you need to copy your file in your document folder then it will works.

Comment: And set delegate method of WebView then you know what is error while loading html file.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, my index file is in:
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/96F63551-0F74-4F52-BED1-9FE38CDD40CB/Documents/MOTHER-APP/`

This path is on the device, i have checked the file is present

Comment: good, then did you checked file size, Some time file is exist on location but file size is zero kb, please check it file size, and set delegate method of web view and debug your application.

Comment: if I use:

`webView.loadHTMLString(indexfile, baseURL: baseUrl)` 
the index page loads but does not include the css/mother.css file

Comment: Hi @Vivek is this correct delegate:
`webView.navigationDelegate = self

                webView.load(request)`

Comment: Hi @Vivek

'********* error on load ********* Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A43C4499-4ECC-4574-8AFE-80ABA888E4CF/Documents/MOTHER-APP/index.html, _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x146482f0>, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A43C4499-4ECC-4574-8AFE-80ABA888E4CF/Documents/MOTHER-APP/index.html}'

Comment: Hi @Vivek but if I use: 
`webView.loadHTMLString(indexfile, baseURL: baseUrl) the index page loads but does not include the css/mother.css` file 

so the file is there and can load, but it does not include the css or js files

Comment: Hi @MarkRussell I have found solution for load css file and java files, Just check my update.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, thank you for the link, but that solution is including files from the bundle directory, not the custom documents directory `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A43C4499-4ECC-4574-8AFE-80ABA888E4CF/Documents/MOTHER-APP`

Comment: Html can't load the css and js from documents directory because of permission issues on real device however it'll work fine for simulator. you need to put your files in cache or temporary directory and load it from there.